# Regex xml string and print groups

Tags: python, regex, xml

I have been trying to use regex to parse through a XML-style string that looks like this:

**Input** 
    `"Joe Doe got a <span class="procedure">X ray</span> <- in April blah blah <span <- class="disease">lacerations</span> blah <span <- class="anatomy">kidney</span>."`

For each span I want to **match** three groups: 
`"<span class="blah">blah</span>" , class, textual content`

**For Example:** 
`<span class="procedure">X ray</span>`
the matches are: 
`<span class="procedure">X ray</span>, procedure, X ray`

Till now I have been able to use `re.search('<.+?>', xml)` to find `<span class="procedure">`

Inspite of using `re.search('<.+?>+, xml)`, I have no luck in finding the other strings instead it gave `<span class="procedure">X ray</span> <- in April>` which isn't the desired result either.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: I did research this topic well before posting this question & am well aware of the multitude of tools that would perform the required tasks much easier. However, it was posed to me to perform this task using regex which is clearly a bit of a challenge due to the limitations of regex and XML/HTML.

Comment: Cheers, glad someone was able to provide an answer before the topic was closed as a duplicate. For future advice: if you lay out what research you've done, and explain "Yes, I know I generally shouldn't do this, but I'm required to as part of a test/homework/etc." it will be less likely to be closed for any reason!

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for the info! Will be sure to apply next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex is not the best for dealing with nested types like XML. But if your question is really that simple `re.findall(r'<span.+?<\/span>', yourstring)` will return your desired results.

Comment: thanks for the assist, this gave me ['<span class="procedure">', '<span <- class="disease">', '<span <- class="anatomy">'] so I tried `re.findall(r'<span.+?<\span>', mystring)` but that returned an empty list.

Comment: Sorry diddnt realize you wanted the whole thing. Ill update the answer.

Comment: `re.findall(r'<span.+?<\/span>', mystring)` also produced an empty string, am I missing something?

Comment: You must be, it works perfectly for me. are you passing in the right string?

Comment: Yup, that worked. It was an environment issue on my end. Thanks!